# Adding nodes with variables windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, windows-forms-designer

I'm having some problems, I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

What I'm trying to do is have a variable that everytime I click a buton its value goes up by 1, therefore changing the index I indicate, although, even when the index changes the node I'm trying to create goes to the node with the index 0.

This is what I have right now:

```cs
private void btnIns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = -1;
    TreeNode subNode1 = new TreeNode(txtNum.Text);
    TreeNode subNode2 = new TreeNode(cbbDisc.Text);

    i++;
    tvwIco.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(subNode1);
    tvwIco.Nodes[0].Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(subNode2);
}
```

Comment: You need a variable *outside* this function to store the value from one call to the next. Make a `private` instance field

Comment: why are you adding to the child of twico.Node[0] instead of the main node tvwico.Node[i]